# Cannot find maven dependency, mysterious jar files

Tags: maven-2

I am trying to build a simple war file which has a few jsps. However I am coming across an odd issue, for some reason during the packaging maven is pulling 4 jar files into the WEB-INF/lib. I have trimmed down all the fat from the pom file, and have grepped for any references to these jars without any success. I cannot figure out where maven is pulling them from. I tried 'mvn dependency:build-classpath' and the classpath is empty. Please help, these jars are corrupt and I cannot deploy this war file because of them.

Thanks,

natasha

Comment: Can you tell us what they are?  And what your pom.xml looks like?

Answer (score 3):

You are very likely getting these dependency transitively and your best weapon to debug this is:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

This should help you to find the culprit.

Just a wild guess: do you have a dependency on **log4j-1.2.15.jar**?

Comment: This helped me find some 'mystery jars' in my war file - just what I needed! They were coming in trasitively from another dependency